# Publishing to Broker database encodes the content

Tags: 2013, broker

Dynamic content in Tridion_Broker database in table COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS is encoded when published from SDL Tridion. Things that are manually inserted in that table from SQL Management studio are readable.

Why is SDL Tridion encoding dynamic content in Tridion_Broker database? How can we see the content in the database?

We are using SQL Server 2012 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Because even if the people does not care to read the Support contract from SDL and does not care to follow the right path to work, still they are not able to play around with the critical pieces.

Anyway, you should not be doing manual entries in the Broker DB or at least not declare that in a public space, as this will be breaking your client's support contract with SDL and you may mess around during an upgrade process.

Comment: We are not working with client's implementation but with our own sandbox. Thank you for the information from your post about the Support contract it is very helpful, but your answer didn't clarify our question. How can we see the content?

Comment: You can try using a some editor like LINQPad